# Maven direct copy as artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which consists of a single ZIP file. I want to export this zip file directly as the resulting artifact of a maven package/install. That is, the only intervention maven would do is directly taking the ZIP file as the artifact.

I tried using Maven Assembly but this creates a ZIp file containing my ZIP file. I want to avoid this redundancy.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't get it. If you have a Maven project, whose output is a ZIP (which can only be done correctly with assemblies), haven't you already achieved your objective? Or do you have a POM and a zip in a sub-folder, and need help formulating the POM so that it can be installed in your local repository?

Comment: What you said last, this module consists only of a zip file that's generated elsewhere, and put on a subfolder. I need my pom to just put this zip file in the nexus repo.

Comment: Ok, the Nexus repo? Should it should do a `deploy` rather than an `install`?

Comment: Part of the install is the deploy goal, right?

Comment: No, the `deploy` phase includes the `install` phase, but not the other way around. The `install` plugin's _only_ job is to install the output from the build in the _local_ repo. The `deploy` plugin's _only_ job is to deploy the installed artifact in the _remote_ repo, such as Nexus.

Comment: Okay so how do I do so that this zip file in a subfolder gets directly deployed?

Comment: I am preparing an answer for you. I may not have it ready until tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) where you can attach the appropriate zip file to the pom artifact. I would suggest to set the packaging to `pom` but add the build-helper-maven-plugin to `install` or `deploy` phase. The configuration can look like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>some file</file>
                  <type>extension of your file </type>
                  <classifier>optional</classifier>
                </artifact>
                ...
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know there was a plugin that could do that. Thanks for the tip! I am upvoting as soon as I have tried it out.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution I think, although it was easier for me to apply Daniel's solution

Comment: I am now indecisive as to which one to mark as an answer :P

Comment: At StackOverflow, it is not unheard of to have an accepted answer with a lower score than another (more accurate) answer. You are, of course, entitled to do as you like. Point-wise, @khmarbaise will probably come out on top from this either way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This POM ought to do the trick. Please remember, this is **not** a typical use-case for Maven.

As you pointed out, an assembly won't do it out of the box, mostly because the `<file>` assembly directive doesn't include an `<unpack>true</unpack>`. So you need some help. I am going to use the `antrun` plugin for this.

The POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>deploy-zip</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>deploy-zip</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-zip</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <unzip src="YOUR_ZIP" dest="${project.build.directory}/temp" />
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>bundle-zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/my-zip.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus</name>
      <url>YOUR_NEXUS_URL</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus</name>
      <url>YOUR_NEXUS_URL</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

And the assembly descriptor (assumed to be in `src/main/assembly`):

```
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>my-zip</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/temp</directory>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

If you do an `mvn deploy` and your credentials are in order, the file should be uploaded to the repository.

If you want others to depend on this, use this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>deploy-zip</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>my-zip</classifier>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

I hope it works out for you.

Comment: This is an effective solution and it's the one I ended up doing since I needed my zip to be my final artifact rather than an additional one. I know it's a stupid requirement but it is what it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=yourArtifact.zip ...` to install it in the local maven repository.
Check out the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: Thanks but that does not do it for me, I need this for a regular maven install. This project is installed by a Jenkins server for which I have no control so I cannot configure Maven goals and parameters like this